# Is it an issue to schedule too many tiny threads?

Tags: python, multithreading

Is there any issue scheduling too many tiny threads that are never overlap?

For instance, what "unexpected" behavior should be expected from something like this in python:

```py
from threading import Timer

def print_num_thread(wait_for=0.1, num_thread=0):
  t = Timer(0.1, print_num_thread, [wait_for, num_thread+1])

  # do something really quick (do << wait_for) like:
  print(f'thread number {num_thread}')

  t.start()

print_num_thread()
```

What are the advantages of this compared to something like:

```py
from time import sleep

def print_num_while(wait_for=0.1, num_while=0):
  while True:
    # do something really quick like:
    print(f'loop_number {num_while}')

    num_while += 1
    sleep(wait_for)

print_num_while()
```

And how about stopping the threads in the first scenario without setting `t.daemon = True` if using some resources?

Comment: Threads are heavy to spawn, if you have many many tasks and want to parallelize them usually you want a threadpool. If you're doing I/O you may want to try asynchronous concurrency

Answer (score 0):

> And how about stopping the threads in the first scenario without
>   setting t.daemon = True if using some resources?

If you set t.daemon to True the thread will not stop but become a daemon. Meaning it should keep running upon program termination. You can kill/stop a thread using thread.kill.
To compare: make a thread that is a demon in your python repl, make a thread that is none, exit python repl, check running processes.

> What are the advantages of this compared to something like:
>      `...`

The first example will not block the thread, while the second one will.

To compare, try:

```
print_num_thread()
print("I GOT HERE")
```

vs:

```
print_num_while()
print("I GOT HERE")
```